# Why isn't Kubernetes service DNS working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, coreos

I have set up DNS in my Kubernetes (v1.1.2+1abf20d) system, on CoreOS/AWS, but I cannot look up services via DNS. I have tried debugging, but cannot for the life of me find out why. This is what happens when I try to look up the kubernetes service, which should always be available:

```
$ ~/.local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf exec busybox-sleep -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.3.0.10
Address 1: 10.3.0.10 ip-10-3-0-10.eu-central-1.compute.internal

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
error: error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: Error executing in Docker Container: 1
```

I have installed the DNS addon according to this spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: kube-dns-v10
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v10
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
        version: v10
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: etcd
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64:2.2.1
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        command:
        - /usr/local/bin/etcd
        - -data-dir
        - /var/etcd/data
        - -listen-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -advertise-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -initial-cluster-token
        - skydns-etcd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: etcd-storage
          mountPath: /var/etcd/data
      - name: kube2sky
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.12
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/kube2sky"
        - --domain=cluster.local
      - name: skydns
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/skydns"
        - -machines=http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -addr=0.0.0.0:53
        - -ns-rotate=false
        - -domain=cluster.local.
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
      - name: healthz
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz:1.0
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        args:
        - -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null
        - -port=8080
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: etcd-storage
        emptyDir: {}
      dnsPolicy: Default  # Don't use cluster DNS.

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: "KubeDNS"
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
  clusterIP: 10.3.0.10
  ports:
  - name: dns
    port: 53
    protocol: UDP
  - name: dns-tcp
    port: 53
    protocol: TCP
```

Why isn't DNS lookup for services working in my Kubernetes setup? Please let me know what other info I need to provide.

Comment: Can you try this debuggin: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20652#issuecomment-193363784. I suspect your dns pod is not able to contact the master, and so the etcd in the dns pod has no dns records. You should be able to verify the ability to talk to the master by creating this pod: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20652#issuecomment-193387557. Can you also try pinging the endpoint of your DNS service (from kubectl get ep --namespace=kube-system).

Comment: @PrashanthB Please see my gist at https://gist.github.com/aknuds1/f076546f040ded4a2f57 for the output of the three debugging commands in your issue.

Comment: @PrashanthB The command `~/.local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf get ep --namespace=kube-system` shows kube-dns, but no endpoints for it.

Comment: Your skydns has ready:false, if even one container is not ready it won't show up as an endpoint. Can you please update your yaml to a more recent verion and give me logs from kube2sky? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/dns/skydns-rc.yaml.in#L1

Comment: @PrashanthB Thanks. I updated the YAML to v11 (as per your link): Logs: ```$ ~/.local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf logs kube-dns-v10-q0jtf --namespace=kube-system -c kube2sky
I0310 13:51:22.623140       1 kube2sky.go:436] Etcd server found: http://127.0.0.1:4001
I0310 13:51:23.626707       1 kube2sky.go:503] Using https://10.3.0.1:443 for kubernetes master
I0310 13:51:23.626828       1 kube2sky.go:504] Using kubernetes API <nil>```

Comment: @PrashanthB There are now two pods created for DNS, do you know why there must be several? Still, only 3/4 are running: https://gist.github.com/aknuds1/d7c0400c2dc56b6d8418.

Comment: Ok, can you give me the output of kubectl logs on kube2sky? I'm assuming that's the one not ready (kubectl get pod -o yaml should show a read: false flag on the container that isn't ready). The kubedns rc should only have 1 replica, you can verify this again via kubectl get rc dns-pod -o yaml, or just via get rc. If it has more than 1, scale it down to 1 (kubectl scale rc dns-pod --replicas=1)

Comment: @PrashanthB It seems that kube2sky is in trouble yeah, it keeps restarting due to a failed health check: `Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.2.100.5:8081/readiness: dial tcp 10.2.100.5:8081: connection refused`. You can see the logs here: https://gist.github.com/aknuds1/1e114e7e0247d5ee04e8. The kube-dns RC has only 1 replica.

Comment: @PrashanthB Any idea why http://10.2.100.5:8081/readiness is unreachable?

Comment: @PrashanthB I found out that I should configure kube2sky via kubeconfig, then it stops failing. However, DNS service lookups still fail :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two things I needed to do:

1. Configure kube2sky via kubeconfig, so that it's properly configured for TLS.
2. Configure kube-proxy via kubeconfig, so that it's properly configured for TLS and finds the master node.

### /etc/kubernetes/kube.conf on master node

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: kube
  cluster:
    server: https://127.0.0.1:443
    certificate-authority: /etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/ssl/etcd/master-client.pem
    client-key: /etc/ssl/etcd/master-client-key.pem
contexts:
- context:
  cluster: kube
  user: kubelet
```

### /etc/kubernetes/kube.conf on worker node

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: local
  cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem
    server: https://<master IP>:443
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/ssl/etcd/worker.pem
    client-key: /etc/ssl/etcd/worker-key.pem
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: local
    user: kubelet
  name: kubelet-context
current-context: kubelet-context
```

### dns-addon.yaml (install this on master)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: kube-dns-v11
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v11
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v11
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
        version: v11
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: etcd
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64:2.2.1
        resources:
          # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
          # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
          # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
          # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting
          # it.
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        command:
        - /usr/local/bin/etcd
        - -data-dir
        - /var/etcd/data
        - -listen-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -advertise-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -initial-cluster-token
        - skydns-etcd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: etcd-storage
          mountPath: /var/etcd/data
      - name: kube2sky
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.14
        resources:
          # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
          # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
          # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
          # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting
          # it.
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            # Kube2sky watches all pods.
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kubernetes-etc
          mountPath: /etc/kubernetes
          readOnly: true
        - name: etcd-ssl
          mountPath: /etc/ssl/etcd
          readOnly: true
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /readiness
            port: 8081
            scheme: HTTP
          # we poll on pod startup for the Kubernetes master service and
          # only setup the /readiness HTTP server once that's available.
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        args:
        # command = "/kube2sky"
        - --domain=cluster.local.
        - --kubecfg-file=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf
      - name: skydns
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
        resources:
          # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
          # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
          # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
          # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting
          # it.
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/skydns"
        - -machines=http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -addr=0.0.0.0:53
        - -ns-rotate=false
        - -domain=cluster.local
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
      - name: healthz
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz:1.0
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        args:
        - -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local \
127.0.0.1 >/dev/null
        - -port=8080
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: etcd-storage
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: kubernetes-etc
        hostPath:
          path: /etc/kubernetes
      - name: etcd-ssl
        hostPath:
          path: /etc/ssl/etcd
      dnsPolicy: Default  # Don't use cluster DNS.
```

### /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-proxy.yaml on master node

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-proxy
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.2
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - proxy
    - --master=https://127.0.0.1:443
    - --proxy-mode=iptables
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ssl-certs-host
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes
      name: kubernetes
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/etcd
      name: kubernetes-certs
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    name: ssl-certs-host
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes
    name: kubernetes
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/etcd
    name: kubernetes-certs
```

### /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-proxy.yaml on worker node

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-proxy
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.1.2
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - proxy
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf
    - --proxy-mode=iptables
    - --v=2
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
        name: "ssl-certs"
      - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/kube.conf
        name: "kubeconfig"
        readOnly: true
      - mountPath: /etc/ssl/etcd
        name: "etc-kube-ssl"
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: "ssl-certs"
      hostPath:
        path: "/usr/share/ca-certificates"
    - name: "kubeconfig"
      hostPath:
        path: "/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf"
    - name: "etc-kube-ssl"
      hostPath:
        path: "/etc/ssl/etcd"
```