# Why isn't Kubernetes service DNS working on Docker Multinode?

Tags: docker, dns, kubernetes

My problem is exactly as described in the thread [Why isn't Kubernetes service DNS working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849569/why-isnt-kubernetes-service-dns-working)

but my question relates to Kubernetes on Docker, how do I fix the issues with DNS when using Kubernetes Docker Multinode.

Comment: I guess you have followed this https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns to setup DNS on Kubernetes. If so can you share the logs of SkyDNS pod by "kubectl logs -c <container log>"

Comment: 2016/03/16 15:31:25 skydns: falling back to default configuration, could not read from etcd: 501: All the given peers are not reachable (failed to propose on members [http://127.0.0.1:4001] twice [last error: Get http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/keys/skydns/config?quorum=false&recursive=false&sorted=false: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connection refused]) [0]
2016/03/16 15:31:25 skydns: ready for queries on . for tcp://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]
2016/03/16 15:31:25 skydns: ready for queries on . for udp://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]

Comment: kube2sky logs `I0317 07:36:35.275393       1 kube2sky.go:462] Etcd server found: http://127.0.0.1:4001
Using https://10.0.0.1:443 for kubernetes master
I0317 07:36:36.277973       1 kube2sky.go:530] Using kubernetes API <nil>
I0317 07:36:36.278673       1 kube2sky.go:598] Waiting for service: default/kubernetes
I0317 07:36:37.280606       1 kube2sky.go:604] Ignoring error while waiting for service default/kubernetes: Get https://10.0.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes: dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: getsockopt: no route to host. Sleeping 1s before retrying.
`

Comment: Did you set "--cluster-dns=192.168.3.10  --cluster-domain=cluster.local" flags for kubelet?

Comment: They are set as part of the kubelet docker startup: [link]https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master.sh

Comment: I think it may be somehow related to the certificates as @aknuds1 mentioned in his post

Comment: Could you show your commands to start it please ? What is your HOST ? Linux or docker-toolbox ?

Comment: I'm running docker containers on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511, 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64. I'm using the following script to run the kube-master [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master.sh) and the following script to run the SkyDNS [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/skydns.yaml.in) I'm updating the the places with {{ pillar }} to the actual values as suggested by the tutorial: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/deployDNS/

Comment: I have opened an issue on [kubernetes github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23111) and put all the logs and the commands that I run

Comment: docker run with 1.2 seems currently broken: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4869 -- it's an old post (1 year). They are trying to run kubelet as a container but it's in progress. They have done some advance with docker 1.10 but I can't tell you if DNS is working with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check with them